# Promises chain incorrect. Doesn't return multiple values

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to return two values from a fetch request:

```
stats.videoCount
stats.viewCount
```

Using the following code, I can return one value correctly, but cannot return both.

The following code returns the video view count.

```
fetch("https://api.promptapi.com/tiktok/hashtag/planttrees", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(treeViewCountResult => console.log(treeViewCountResult.challengeInfo.stats.viewCount))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
```

But this code won't return two values:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(treeVideoResult => console.log(treeVideoResult.challengeInfo.stats.videoCount))
.then(treeViewCountResult => console.log(treeViewCountResult.challengeInfo.stats.viewCount))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error))
```

treeVideoResult and treeViewCountResult will work individually, but not together.

How am I chaining the promises incorrectly?

Comment: `console.log` returns undefined. Which means every `then` from the first log will have undefined as it's argument (parameter? I confuse the two).

Comment: You are returning nothing in the first then. So there is  no promise to catch in the second then.

Comment: If I comment out either the treeVideoResult line, or the treeViewCountResult line, it correctly returns a value. How do I return both values?

Comment: Return it to what? How are you using the data coming back from the fetch?

Comment: I want to log out 2 numerical values to the console. Either a viewcount, or a videocount. I can return one value correctly, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a single object. You don't need two then for it.

```
fetch("https://api.promptapi.com/tiktok/hashtag/planttrees", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result.challengeInfo.stats.videoCount, resutl.challengeInfo.stats.viewCount))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding what's happening with each `then`.

Everything in the example works up to this line:

```js
.then(treeVideoResult => console.log(treeVideoResult.challengeInfo.stats.videoCount))
```

The result of `response.json()` is being given to the then function as `treeVideoResult`, a property of which, is being logged by `console.log`. However `console.log` returns `undefined`.

This means that in this line:

```js
.then(treeViewCountResult => console.log(treeViewCountResult.challengeInfo.stats.viewCount))
```

`treeViewCountResult` is `undefined`. So it should throw an error (although I haven't checked).

If we want to return multiple values from one fetch call, consider using an object.

```js
fetch("https://api.promptapi.com/tiktok/hashtag/planttrees", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((treeVideoResult) => ({
    videoCount: treeVideoResult.challengeInfo.stats.videoCount,
    viewCount: treeVideoResult.challengeInfo.stats.viewCount,
  }))
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    doSomthingElseFunction(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

**TLDR:** the return of one `then` is the input of the next. Any function using the data returned by `fetch` *must* be called inside a `then` (if not using  async/await).

Comment: Thanks for that thorough response. It does throw an undefined error, as you said. I accepted Vo Quoc Thang's answer, as it's the most economical, but your explanation is clear.